# objective-c: ScrollView scroll to left & right direction

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

How can i scroll my scrollview to a specific point in both left & right directions.I have tried with the following piece of code but it is entering into infinite loop.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    if (xCoord > scrollView.contentOffset.x )
    {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(xCoord + 160, 0);
    }
    else if(xCoord < scrollView.contentOffset.x )
    {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(xCoord - 160, 0);
    }

    xCoord = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

I just wanted scroll my scrollview by 160inches in both directions whenever user drags the screen. 
In my case i have few labels on scrollview, when i scroll the scrollview it has to scroll specific to label width(160) .

Comment: Did you set the contentSize for your scrollView?

Comment: What is your scrollview's width ?

Comment: @GenieWanted: i set the scrollview contentsize as **scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1280,65);**

Comment: @iManan : 1280 is my scrollview width

Comment: @Javeed: So do you want to scroll content upto 160 px at the time ?

Comment: @iManan : yes, exactlly

Comment: @Javeed: Ok so you set content size to 1280. And is scrollview within whole screen ?? Means edge to edge - 0 to 320 ??

Comment: @iManan : yes, my scrollview content size is 1280 & it is within whole screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try  these,

1. Set your scrollview `contentSize` (should be higher than the
   `frame`)

   self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 900);
2. Uncheck the `autoLayout` checkbox in the xib
3. Assign the delegate and `setScrollEnabled` property to true.

> ```
>  [self.scrollView setDelegate:self];
> ```

```
> [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
```

**Note:** Only set your initial visible area as `frame` and total content size as `contentSize`.

Comment: i have done everything as you mentioned but no use. In my case i have few labels on scrollview, when i scroll the scrollview it has to scroll specific to label width(160) .

Comment: @Javeed: only set your initial visible area as 'frame' and total content size as contentSize.